# Analyze big data in R on EC2 server

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-ec2, bigdata, dbi

I managed to load and merge the 6 heavy excel files I had from my RStudio instance (on EC2 server) into one single table in PostgreQSL (linked with RDS).

Now this table has **14** columns and **2,4** Million rows.
The size of the table in **PostgreSQL** is **1059MB**.
The **EC2** instance is a **t2.medium**.

I wanted to analyze it, so I thought I could simply load the table with `DBI` package and perform different operations on it.

So I did:

```
my_big_df <- dbReadTable(con, "my_big_table")
my_big_df  <- unique(my_big_df)
```

and my RStudio froze, out of memory...

My questions would be:
1) Is what I have been doing (to handle big tables like this) a ok/good practice?
2) If yes to 1), is the only way to be able to perform the `unique()` operation or other similar operations to increase the EC2 server memory?
3) If yes to 2), how can I know to which extent should I increase the EC2 server memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Run your queries on the database instead of reading the entire table into memory?

Comment: but I would need to use SQL queries isn't it? Can't I continue to use R even with such big volumes?

Comment: Yes, SQL queries are needed to query a postgresql database. Try a bigger EC2 instance if you can't use SQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbReadTable` convert the entire table to a `data.frame`, which is not what you want to do for such a big tables.

As @cory told you, you need to extract the required info using `SQL` queries.
You can do that with `DBI` using combinations of `dbSendQuery`,`dbBind`,`dbFetch` or `dbGetQuery`.

For example, you could define a function to get the required data

```
filterBySQLString <- function(databaseDB,sqlString){
    sqlString <- as.character(sqlString)
    dbResponse <- dbSendQuery(databaseDB,sqlString)
    requestedData <- dbFetch(dbResponse)
    dbClearResult(dbResponse)

    return(requestedData)
}

# write your query to get unique values
SQLquery <- "SELECT * ...
             DISTINCT  ..."

my_big_df <- filterBySQLString(myDB,SQLquery)
my_big_df  <- unique(my_big_df)
```

If you cannot use `SQL`, then you have two options:

1) stop using Rstudio and try to run your code from the terminal or via `Rscript`.

2) beef up your instance

Comment: Thanks @fra ! I guess I need to get used to the idea of not using R for data analysis then... Would you know about other solutions where R can be used for example with Spark ( as SparkR) ?